# clear all values of hashmap except two key/value pair

Tags: java, collections

I have a `HashMap` with hundred of key/value pairs.

Now I have to delete all key/values except **2** key/value.
I have use this way :

```
if(map!=null){
     String search = map.get(Constants.search);
     String context = map.get(Constants.context);
     map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put(Constants.search,search);
     map.put(Constants.context,context);
}
```

But java 8 introduced `removeIf()` for these kind of condition. How can I solve this problem with `removeIf()` method ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to it like this :

```
map.keySet().removeIf(k -> !(k.equals(Constants.search) || k.equals(Constants.context)));
```

It will iterate over the `keys` and remove the ones for those the `key` is not one of or two required `keys`

Answer (score 6):

## yet shorter *(since Java 2)*:

```
map.keySet().retainAll(myKeys);
```

Since keySet() still wraps the original HashMap, its #retainAll() affects the Map.

myKeys is a collection of keys, e.g.: **myKeys = List.of("key1", "key2")**

Comment: retainAll() only accepts a Collection. So code example should be map.keySet().retainAll(Set.of("key1", "key2")); // Java 9+ syntax

Comment: @rmuller , many thanks. I'm fixing the code example from the incorrect `.retainsAll("key1", "key2")` into **.retainAll(Set.of("key1", "key2"))**

Comment: Just nitpicking. IMHO Set.of() is neater in this example